# How can i create a drawing app in flutter where i can draw lines shapes in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, canvas, flutter-layout, drawing

I have been trying to create a app where end user can draw or create a design of his farm and show direction of pipes on his land. First i tried to search in flutter because my app is in flutter then python and html canvas also. In flutter, free hand drawing app can be created using gesture ditector, paint widget. But i was not able to find proper option to crate simple line or rectangle.

Comment: check out https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html

Comment: This is also a pretty nice article about the topic https://blog.codemagic.io/flutter-custom-painter/

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to draw a line,

**NOTE**: We simply are storing the *starting* and *ending* *positions* of the pointer.

```
 onPanStart:
                                          (DragStartDetails details) {
                                        setState(
                                          () {
                                            RenderBox object =
                                                context.findRenderObject();
                                            Offset _localPosition =
                                                object.globalToLocal(
                                                    details.globalPosition);
                                            List.from(linePoints)
                                              ..add(_localPosition);
                                          },
                                        );
                                      },
```

This way you'll store the starting position of the line that you want to draw.
Then keep updating another variable called `endPosition` in `onPanUpdate` the same way and in `onPanEnd` add the `endPosition` variable to the `linePoints` list.

```
onPanUpdate:
                                          (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                                        RenderBox object =
                                            context.findRenderObject();
                                        _endPosition =
                                            object.globalToLocal(
                                                details.globalPosition);
                                      },

onPanEnd:(details){List.from(linePoints)..add(_Position);}
```